# Different combinations of n numbers in ascending order in C

Tags: c, while-loop, numbers

I want to write a function that shows all the different combinations of n numbers in ascending order in C.

For example, if n=2:
01, 02, 03, ..., 09, 12, ..., 79, 89.

The function should be named as follows:

```
void ft_print_combn(int n);
```

I tried to do it this way but it's giving me bad and I don't know how to change my code to give the correct sequence:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void    ft_putchar(char a)
{
    write(1, &a, 1);
}

void    ft_print_combn(int n)
{
    int combn[n];
    int p;
    int pos;
    int position;

    if (n <= 0 || n >= 10)
        return ;
    else
    {
        p = 0;
        pos = 0;
        while (p < n)
        {
            combn[p] = p;
            //ft_putchar(combn[p] + '0');
            p++;
        }
        
        while(n-position-1>=1 && n-(position+1)-1>=0)
        {
                while(combn[n-pos-1]>combn[n-(pos+1)-1])
                {
                        while(p<=n)
                        {    
                            //ft_putchar(combn[pos] + '0');
                            //combn[n-pos-1]=combn[n-(pos+1)-1]+1;
                            printf("%d[%d] > %d[%d]\n", combn[n-p-1], n-p-1 , combn[n-(p+1)-1], n-(p+1)-1);
                            combn[n-p-1]=combn[n-(p+1)-1]+1;
                            p++;
                        }
                pos++;
                }
        combn[n-pos-1]=combn[n-(pos+1)-1]+1;
        position++;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    ft_print_combn(4);   
}
```

Comment: The value `position` is used before before it has been assigned or initialized.

Comment: Step 1: Increase your compilers warning level and **fix all** warnings before executing the program

Comment: Step#2: rewrite your while() loops into sane for() loops.

Comment: If you want a recursive solution, you need a helper-function so that you can pass stuff like: starting-digit, string-constructed-so-far, remaining-number-of-digits-to-add.

Comment: To clarify what @4386427 meant by increasing the warning level: when compiling the program, you need to add `-Wall` to your command, e.g. `gcc -Wall program.c -o program`

Comment: Sorry Maria, why do you wrap a `write(1, &a, 1);` instead of using the normal, buffered, more efficient `putchar(3)` call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first combination has all digits set to their minimum value, starting at 0 for the leftmost digit. For four digits:

```
0123
```

The last combination has all digits set to their maximum value, starting at 10 - *N* for an *N* digit number. For four digits:

```
6789
```

The combinations inbetween are found by "incrementing" the previous combination. This involves a search from right to left looking for the rightmost digit that is not at its maximum value. For example, if the current combination for 4 digits is:

```
0589
 ^ this is the rightmost digit that can be incremented
```

Form the next combination by incrementing that digit and setting all digits to its right to one more than the previous digit:

```
0678
 ^ this is the first changed digit, the digits to the right are set sequentially
```

Here is one possible implementation, using a bunch of nested `while` and `do while` loops:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void    ft_putchar(char a)
{
    write(1, &a, 1);
}

void    ft_print_combn(int n)
{
    int combn[n];
    int p;

    if (n <= 0 || n >= 10)
        return ;
    else
    {
        p = 0;
        /* Set first combination. */
        while (p < n)
        {
            combn[p] = p;
            p++;
        }

        while (p > 0)
        {
            int maxdigit = 10;

            /* Print current combination. */
            for (p = 0; p < n; p++)
            {
                ft_putchar(combn[p] + '0');
            }
            /*
             * Work out next combination, if any.
             *
             * Search from right to left looking for a digit that can be
             * incremented. E.g. rightmost digit can be incremented if
             * less than 9, otherwise the digit to its left can be incremented
             * if less than 8, etc.
             */
            p = n;
            while (p--)
            {
                int digit = combn[p];

                /*
                 * Maximum digit value decreases during search from
                 * right to left.
                 */
                if (digit < --maxdigit)
                {
                    /*
                     * Found a digit that can be incremented.
                     *
                     * Increment that digit and reset all the digits to its
                     * right to their minimum allowed value.
                     */
                    do
                    {
                        combn[p++] = ++digit;
                    }
                    while (p < n);
                    /* Print separator. */
                    ft_putchar(',');
                    ft_putchar(' ');
                    /* Break out of search. */
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        ft_putchar('\n');
    }
}

int main()
{
    ft_print_combn(4);   
}
```

Output:

```
0123, 0124, 0125, 0126, 0127, 0128, 0129, 0134, 0135, 0136, 0137, 0138, 0139, 0145, 0146, 0147, 0148, 0149, 0156, 0157, 0158, 0159, 0167, 0168, 0169, 0178, 0179, 0189, 0234, 0235, 0236, 0237, 0238, 0239, 0245, 0246, 0247, 0248, 0249, 0256, 0257, 0258, 0259, 0267, 0268, 0269, 0278, 0279, 0289, 0345, 0346, 0347, 0348, 0349, 0356, 0357, 0358, 0359, 0367, 0368, 0369, 0378, 0379, 0389, 0456, 0457, 0458, 0459, 0467, 0468, 0469, 0478, 0479, 0489, 0567, 0568, 0569, 0578, 0579, 0589, 0678, 0679, 0689, 0789, 1234, 1235, 1236, 1237, 1238, 1239, 1245, 1246, 1247, 1248, 1249, 1256, 1257, 1258, 1259, 1267, 1268, 1269, 1278, 1279, 1289, 1345, 1346, 1347, 1348, 1349, 1356, 1357, 1358, 1359, 1367, 1368, 1369, 1378, 1379, 1389, 1456, 1457, 1458, 1459, 1467, 1468, 1469, 1478, 1479, 1489, 1567, 1568, 1569, 1578, 1579, 1589, 1678, 1679, 1689, 1789, 2345, 2346, 2347, 2348, 2349, 2356, 2357, 2358, 2359, 2367, 2368, 2369, 2378, 2379, 2389, 2456, 2457, 2458, 2459, 2467, 2468, 2469, 2478, 2479, 2489, 2567, 2568, 2569, 2578, 2579, 2589, 2678, 2679, 2689, 2789, 3456, 3457, 3458, 3459, 3467, 3468, 3469, 3478, 3479, 3489, 3567, 3568, 3569, 3578, 3579, 3589, 3678, 3679, 3689, 3789, 4567, 4568, 4569, 4578, 4579, 4589, 4678, 4679, 4689, 4789, 5678, 5679, 5689, 5789, 6789
```

Comment: Best solution, though they're only allowed to use while loop, and for loop is forbidden.
I think the person who asked can do the work around.

Answer (score 1):

It is much easier to do it with a recursive function (as suggested by @4386427):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void combn(int start, int n, const char* s)
{
  if(n==0){
      printf("%s\n", s);
      return;
  } 
  for(int i=start;i<=9;i++){      
      char s2[11];
      sprintf(s2, "%s%i",s, i);
      combn(i+1,n-1, s2);
  }
}

void ft_print_combn(int n)
{
    if (n>=1 && n<=10)
      combn(0,n,"");
}

int main (int argc, char* args[])
{
    ft_print_combn(3);
}
```

Comment: This is pretty close to what I had in mind.... and it's the nice simple way of doing things... no complicated logic - just code easy to read and understand. Should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can use that method for print all code with N digits
n need > O

```
#include <stdio.h>

int int_len(int nb) {
    int len = 1;
    while (nb > 0){
        len++;
        nb /= 10;
    }
    return len - 1;
}

void ft_combi(int n)
{
    int combi = n / n; // add error if n = 0
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        combi *= 10;
    for (int i = 0; i < combi; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j > int_len(i) - n; j--)
            printf("0");
        if (i == 0)
            printf("\n");
        else
            printf("%d\n", i);
    }
}

int main()
{
    ft_combi(2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution will do the job (read the comments attached to see how it works):

```
#include <getopt.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* Set of available chars in the order they must be considered. */
char alpha[] = "0123456789";

/* hold the pointers to the chars to print a solution */
char *sol[sizeof alpha];
static char *sep = ""; /* initial separator is nothing (no separator) */

void
print_numbers(
        int   n,    /* number of characters to generate per sol. */
        char *from, /* where to take the chars from */
        int   l)    /* actual string length */
{
    if (n) { /* we need to descend recursively as we have still chars to add */
        char *p;
        /* from the next available char to the end of the string
         * of available chars */
        for (p = from+1; *p; p++) {
            /* save the pointer to be able to print it */
            sol[l] = p;
            /* call recursively with updated parameters */
            print_numbers(n-1, p, l+1);
        }
    } else {
        /* print the solution (the characters point to in sol array) */
        sol[l] = NULL; /* end the array of pointers */
        printf("%s", sep); /* print the separator string */
        sep = ", "; /* change separator into a comma and a space */
        int i;
        for (i = 0; sol[i]; i++) /* print the chars pointed to in sol */
            putchar(*sol[i]);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int opt;
    int n = 2; /* default print two digits, as stated in SO question */

    /* we use getopt(3) to process a possible option -n to specify the
     * actual number of characters we want to print. */
    while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "n:")) != EOF) {
        switch (opt) {
        /* option -n allows to select any other length */
        case 'n': n = atoi(optarg); break;
        }
    }

    /* initially call the recursive function */
    print_numbers(n, alpha, 0);

    /* print a last \n so we end in a new line */
    puts("");
}
```

It will print the sample you posted if run without parameters:

```
$ asc
01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08, 09, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 56, 57, 58, 59, 67, 68, 69, 78, 79, 89
$  _
```

or if you use `-n` :

```
$ asc -n 3
012, 013, 014, 015, 016, 017, 018, 019, 023, 024, 025, 026, 027, 028, 029, 034, 035, 036, 037, 038, 039, 045, 046, 047, 048, 049, 056, 057, 058, 059, 067, 068, 069, 078, 079, 089, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 156, 157, 158, 159, 167, 168, 169, 178, 179, 189, 234, 235, 236, 237, 238, 239, 245, 246, 247, 248, 249, 256, 257, 258, 259, 267, 268, 269, 278, 279, 289, 345, 346, 347, 348, 349, 356, 357, 358, 359, 367, 368, 369, 378, 379, 389, 456, 457, 458, 459, 467, 468, 469, 478, 479, 489, 567, 568, 569, 578, 579, 589, 678, 679, 689, 789
$ _
```